# Не переведена информация об очередях проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Вдруг показали такое (при нажатии на "Очереди проверок - Все"). Не знаю как часто оно бывает и кому показывается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS. Зашел в проверки на мете, там почему-то переведена только половина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводы добавил. Ссылки не привожу, лень копировать, если честно, да и вряд ли их кто-то будет смотреть. А если и будут, то всегда можно по исходной строке найти.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.4.20.39115

Уже подхватилось. Выглядит так:

> [image: Кто тут крайний в очереди?]

Обновление по результатам новых оригинальных строк:

> [image: Лучше длинная очередь из людей, чем короткая из автомата]

Comment: А почему вдруг эти окна стали показываться? Мне сегодня на каждую очередь было, что я получил доступ туда (за 500 репутации) , доступ сюда (за 3000 репутации).

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня та же история. Предполагаю, что так демонстрируют новый функционал, чтобы о нём узнали не только новые участники, но и старожилы.

Comment: @Эникейщик теперь для подтверждения надо выяснить [как включить эти блоки обратно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363639/339911) :)

Comment: Показался один блок, как минимум окно про "Предлагаемые правки" переведено :)

Comment: @Эникейщик там все переведены, посмотреть тоже можно - на MSE ответили.

Comment: Ага, я видел. Но там нужно во всякие инструменты лезть, что делать неохота 

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил скрин текущего состояния.

Comment: на мете почему-то только половина переведена (добавил скрин в тело вопроса)

Comment: @Эникейщик они опять изменили строки. Сравните текст на картинках. Видимо, переводы не стоит добавлять пока оригинальные строки не устаканятся месяц-другой.